# Python: Function printing boolean return values

Tags: python, recursion

I was working in a small problem in python. This is the problem -

Given an array of ints, compute recursively if the array contains a 6. We'll use the convention of considering only the part of the array that begins at the given index. In this way, a recursive call can pass index+1 to move down the array. The initial call will pass in index as 0.

```
array6([1, 6, 4], 0) → true
array6([1, 4], 0) → false
array6([6], 0) → true
```

This is the solution which i came up with.

```
def array6(intList, index):
    if len(intList) < index + 1:
        print(False)
    else:
        if intList[index] == 6:
            print(True)
        else:
            array6(intList, index + 1)
```

The script seems to work correctly, except when i change print to return statements and call it as : print(array6([1, 6, 4], 0)) it displays "None" in the console. Why is this? It should ideally display True or False - Right? Or am i missing something in the script?

Comment: You forgot to return `array6` most probably. Could you show us the code with `return`?

Answer (score 1):

When the execution moves to the most inner `else` statement, no `return` statement is found, so `None` is assumed.

In order to solve that, do:

```
return array6(intList, index + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you forgot to `return` the function `array6(intList, index+1)`. It's crucial in recursive functions that all blocks of your  `if-else-if` chain are returning something. You get a `None` whenever the function is not returning anything.

This is what the whole code will look like - (*look at the comment to know where you went wrong*)

```
def array6(intList, index):
    if len(intList) < index + 1:
        return False
    else:
        if intList[index] == 6:
            return True
        else:
            # you forgot the return here
            return array6(intList, index + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

All Python functions return something.  If you do not explicitly return then the return value is None.  You are not returning anything, but you were close:

```
def array6(intList, index):
    if len(intList) < index + 1:
        return False
    else:
        if intList[index] == 6:
            return True
        else:
            return array6(intList, index + 1)
```

Also, you can remove a level of indentation like this

```
def array6(intList, index):
    if len(intList) < index + 1:
        return False
    if intList[index] == 6:
        return True
    return array6(intList, index + 1)
```

Any time an `if` has a `return` inside it, you can remove the follow `else` and de-dent as the function will have already returned.